# Change between ASC and DESC sort for table

Tags: php, html

This is the column I am sorting:

```
<th><a href="?sort=date">Dato</a></th>
```

This is how I am sorting:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
                  
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'date')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY date DESC";
}
                  
$result = $link->query($sql);
```

How can I add so when the user presses the column again, it will `ORDER BY date ASC` instead of DESC?

Comment: `?sort=date&dir=asc`, create this string dynamically and flip it accordingly…

Comment: @deceze How should I flip it by user interaction?

Comment: `?sort=date&dir=<?php echo $_GET['dir'] == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'; ?>`, as a very rough outline…

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a direction variable (this might be simpler if all your code is in the same PHP file)

```
<?php

$direction = 'ASC'; // default

if($_GET['direction'] == 'ASC'){
      $direction = 'DESC';
}

echo '<a href="?sort=date&direction='.$direction.'">Dato</a>';

?>
```

Then just concatenate the $direction variable with your query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
                  
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'date')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY date "; //removed your DESC from here, please note!!
}
if ($_GET['direction'])
{
    $direction = ($_GET['direction']=='ASC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC');
    $sql .= " ".$direction;
}
              
$result = $link->query($sql);
```

Comment: Do make sure to validate that direction is only possibly `ASC` or `DESC`, or you have created for yourself an SQL injection vulnerability…

Answer (score -1):

bear in might, i didnt check it.

The idea is to add a minus symbol if you want to reverse the order between ASC and DESC, so if its already sorted by date then simply add a minus before.

Later on just remove the minus (if its present) and reverse the order. Also you should make a function for you to create the th-tag.

in view

```
<th><a href="?sort=<?= ((isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'date') ? '-' : '') ?>date">Dato</a></th>
```

in controller

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM table ";
$sortColumn = (isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : '');
$direction = 'ASC';
if (strlen($sortColumn) > 0 && substr($sortColumn, 0, 1) == '-') {
    $sortColumn = substr($sortColumn, 1);
    $direction = 'DESC';
}
if (isAllowedSearchColumn($sortColumn)) {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . $sortColumn . ' ' . $direction . ' ';
}
$result = $link->query($sql);
```

update for Nico Haase: in theory should have a good function which checks for the sort column, as an example follows a possible implementation of the function.

```
function isAllowedSearchColumn($sortColumn) {
    return in_array($sortColumn, [
        'date',
        'column2',
        'column3',
        // and so on
    ]);
}
```

Comment: That does not look good, as it opens the magic box of SQL injections. Please do never ever use such code in production, unless you want to be hacked ;)

Comment: explain what exactly you mean? there should be a function to check if the column exists which is isAllowedSearchColumn. so pls explain to make how there could be any SQL injections ;)

Comment: Where's that function? Don't use it only in theory. If you skipped it, it's not too hard to inject some `DROP TABLE` into your sort parameter

Comment: Usually when you start allowing to sort your table, you dont allow only one column to be sortable. You are right, it was my mistake assuming the person would like to be able to sort other columns too. I thought i would push him/her in the right direction. But please tell me it wasnt obvious what a function called isAllowedSearchColumn would do. Also he/she would get an exception running this code anyways because the function wasnt defined. So there was a action from original poster necessary anyways.

Comment: @NicoHaase Could you come with a solution that you suggest, please?

Comment: @Anefi3 is there anything wrong with the approaches given in this answer (validate for existing columns and use nothing else), or in the other answer (use one parameter for the sort column, and one for the direction, while filtering both values for allowed values?)